# Why a torus knot is a prime knot?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Why a [torus knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot) is a [prime knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_knot)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you looking for an accessible proof in the literature? If so, there are two proofs (one very direct and geometric, the other brief and algebraic) on page 95 of "Knots" Gerhard Burde and Heiner Zieschang.

Comment: Thank you for the good reference with down-to-earth proofs!

Comment: No problem at all.